# HTML input with webkitdirectory attribute has different default sorting order on different machines

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, input, webkitdirectory

I developed a web component to upload all the files in the subfolders of a folder using an HTML Input with the `webkitdirectory` attribute but I noticed a strange bug in the sort order of the subfolders when I iterate through the files list of the input using Javascript on different machines.

I tested on several machines running on Windows 10, 11, or Ubuntu 22 and **the subfolders are sorted alphabetically in ascending order** but on one specific Windows 11 machine, they were sorted in **descending** order.

Here is the Typescript code that handles the input:

```
const files = Array.from((event.target as HTMLInputElement).files || [])

const filesByDirectory = R.groupBy(files, (file) =>
    file.webkitRelativePath.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/")
)

for (const folder of filesByDirectory) {
    await this.uploadFiles(filesByDirectory[folder], folder.split("/").pop() as string)
}
```

I thought that the default sorting order of the subfolders would always be consistent, alphabetical and ascending order, but it seems it isn't.

In the meantime I added a line to sort the folders list before uploading but still I would like to understand why is it different for that machine? And what is the underlying rule or default?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any specified order and I wouldn't assume any. [specs](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/) Sorting by modification date sounds as sensible as sorting by name for instance. Can't you just sort your Array the way you want?

Comment: @Kaiido That's what I ended up doing but I was still wondering why that specific machine had a different sorting order than the rest. Indeed, I wasn't able to find any specs about the sorting, it mentions it is an ordered list but no mention of the type of order.

Comment: I honestly don't know but that seems to be at the OS level since on my macOS, I get an apparently arbitrary order, but the same one on every browser: I couldn't link it to any of the available metadata, nor even from any ordering available in the OS file explorer. The point being, don't assume anything. I'll post an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, [the specs](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/) don't require any defined ordering, and it seems that browsers do defer to the OS to set that ordering.
On my macOS system I have an apparently arbitrary order: Files aren't sorted by name, nor by date modified or created, nor by size, nor by type, nor by any other rule that the OS file explorer (Finder) offers for sorting. But, all browsers do return that same order for the same folder.

So you shouldn't rely on any particular ordering and instead convert the `FileList` object you receive to an `Array`* and sort that as you wish.

<sup>* OP contains an example on how to do that.</sup>